# How to Installing compas with rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

I am building a rails application and I want to install compass.
I put this on my Gemfile

```
gem "compass-rails", "~> 2.0.alpha.0"
```

I am trying to import the file 
@import "compass"
and it seems that is not founding the file.
What more should I do except from the gem installation ?

Comment: If you do 'gem list' does it appear in your list of installed gems?

Comment: What's the name of the file you're putting the `@import` into?

Comment: It does appear in my list,
It now compiles the scss but when I am trying to visit the site I am
getting this error. 
"File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.scs"